# Ruby undefined method `copy_stream' for IO:Class

Tags: ruby

I want to download almost 2GB size zip files (builds) on the target server. For that I have written the following piece of code:

```
def download_file(src, dest, build_name)
  begin
       if !File.file?("#{dest}/#{build_name}")
        $LOG.debug "#{dest}/#{build_name} does not exist"
        $LOG.info "Downloading #{build_name} to #{dest}"

        destination = "#{dest}/#{build_name}"

        download = open(src)
        IO.copy_stream(download, destination)

        $LOG.info "Downloading #{build_name} completed succesfully.\n"

  rescue => e
    puts e
  end
end
```

But it is giving the following error message:

```
 undefined method `copy_stream' for IO:Class
```

Need help in fixing this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am using jruby 1.6.7 (ruby 1.9.2).

Comment: weird. mine has it `jruby 1.6.7 (ruby-1.9.2-p312) (2012-02-22 3e82bc8)`. `IO.copy_stream #=> wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)` Possibly a typo or overridden `IO` class?

Comment: And updating isn't an option?  Have you even specified the `--1.9` switch?

Comment: It could very well be a forgotten `--1.9` option or `JRUBY_OPTS=--1.9` env variable